# How to maintain text clarity of image while zooming?

Tags: iphone, image, zooming, image-editing

I am developing an app for a magazine and simultaneously  I am creating images for those magazines using photo shop.

But, when I zoom these images, the text quality is getting loosed.
I have referred to other iPad magazines like India Today. In that, even though I zoom to maximum extent, text quality is too good.

how is that possible? My each image size is almost 800 KB. Even then, when I zoom, I loose the clarity of image. How to maintain the quality of text even when I zoom?

Is that something to do with photoshop editing or coding?

Comment: which size of image  you are created

Comment: I am creating image with 900 X 1100 size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the following table for our iPhone/iPad projects when the OS target is 3.2 or above.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @neon.. Here I am not talking about the application icon images. I am talking about the images to render on UIImageView. Regarding image format, image properties etc.

Comment: But still it's depends on the size of the image which you are created also when put that images into your application that image name post fix with"@2x.png" ex:- back@2x.png

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using raster graphics you are in a losing battle of file size vs. zoom quality.  Text is natively vector and scales beautifully as you zoom, so you are much better off rendering text as text rather than generating text as an image in Photoshop.  There are many ways to accomplish this, one being to have the image be a background layer and the text be a UILabel above the image.

Comment: Guys.. Here many ppl are talking regarding coding. Here I am not using any text view or text on the image. That image itself contains complete text, images etc. I am using an image here. I want to know how to create an image in photo shop such that text quality retain even after zooming?